# Java listener when insert fired on any one specific Oracle table

Tags: java, oracle, scheduler

Thanks your viewing my question. 
I am not aware of any mechanism where I can design something like, If I insert something inside a specific table say EMP_NAME my java listener will get called.
Any help would be highly appreciated.. I will post the answer if I get a resolution which I am doing in parallel.
I want this to happen like when there is a insert in table then only there should be a hit on my java processor class. Not something like kistner which keeps of hitting oracle all the time.

Comment: What are the things that you have tried so far? Please make sure to follow the guidelines here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you talking about Database Change Notification?

Comment: Yes my intention was to have minimum hits of the DB by the server..

Comment: Its developed now... and I have implemented a scheduler for this as I felt that is the best option as of now..